# Ghost Inspector test automation and varification Code

Tags: failing-tests, test-automation

I have a Apex page that I need to test using ghost Inspector. I used chrome Extension to record my screen from the login section. The problem i am having is that ghost inspector is failing after login due to verification code. How do I over come this so salesforce no longer asks for Verification number and would let the ghost inspector login as  me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a lot about Ghost Inspector - but if you know the IP addresses the logins will be coming from you can whitelist them to prevent requiring a verification code. Steps are in the [Salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_networkaccess.htm&type=0&language=en_US).

1. From Setup, enter Network Access in the Quick Find box, then select Network Access.
2. Click New.
3. Enter a valid IP address in the Start IP Address field and a higher IP address in the End IP Address field.
   The start and end addresses define the range of allowable IP addresses from which users can log in, including the start and end values. If you want to allow logins from a single IP address, enter the same address in both fields.
   The start and end IP addresses must be in an IPv4 range and include no more than 33,554,432 addresses (225, a /7 CIDR block).
4. Optionally, enter a description for the range. For example, if you maintain multiple ranges, enter details about the part of your network that corresponds to this range.
5. Click Save.

Comment: hey thank you for the respond , but Is it really based on IP address? I mean generally when I login with chrome its okay, but when I login with FireFox or IE, with same computer and IP address,  then it asks for verification as well

Comment: It's also based on cookies stored in the browser. If you verify with a particular browser and tell Salesforce to remember you and not require verification it may still ask you to verify if you change browsers because the cookie isn't shared between browsers.

Comment: thanks for the reply , for the range of start and end IP address, here is the list 52.4.55.112 52.20.108.143 52.201.131.218 52.205.11.111 . would 52.4.55.112 be start and 52.205.11.111 be the end?

Comment: That looks okay to me but I am not a networking expert so I can't say for sure if that's a valid range.

Comment: Also worth noting that the network access tool is smart enough to catch errors (e.g., if your range is invalid because it's too large or the end address is smaller than the start address) so it should tell you if something is wrong (within reason).

Answer (score 2):

As John Towers said in another answer, you have to add the IP address of the Ghost Inspector server from where it is originated.

In their website they have listed down all the IP addresses from where the tests will generate. https://ghostinspector.com/docs/test-running-ip-addresses/

I believe the IP address is dynamic and you have to add all the IP addresses. If you can filter out the IP address, please post an answer describing the process.

Comment: Thank you for the reply , its working with the ip addresses.